# Retrieve a window handle whitin outlook

Tags: c#, com, outlook, vsto, pinvoke

I'm working on a custom outlook addin where I need to subclass the appointment window. This works basically pretty well following the principles mentioned in the following ariticle:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27262/Additional-custom-panel-in-Microsoft-Outlook

I'm struggeling by getting the handle to the social connector within the new appointment window.
[image]

I've tryied out a few approaches (FindWindow, FindWindowEx, EnumChildWindow) but none of them gave me the correct handle.

Here you can find a small addin project to have a quick look at it.
[Download](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/66056681/Addin.zip)

Or have a quick look at this abstract

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;

namespace FindSocialConnector._2013
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Delegate for the EnumChildWindows method
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hWnd">Window handle</param>
        /// <param name="parameter">Caller-defined variable; we use it for a pointer to our list</param>
        /// <returns>True to continue enumerating, false to bail.</returns>
        public delegate bool EnumWindowProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr parameter);

        /// <summary>
        /// Hält den Klassennamen des NewAppointment Windows.
        /// </summary>
        public const string NewAppointmentWindowClass = "rctrl_renwnd32";

        private Inspectors _inspectors;

        /// <summary>
        /// The EnumChildWindows function enumerates the child windows that belong to the specified parent window by passing the handle to each child window, 
        /// in turn, to an application-defined callback function. EnumChildWindows continues until the last child window is enumerated or the callback function returns FALSE.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="parentHandle">
        /// Handle to the parent window whose child windows are to be enumerated.
        /// If this parameter is NULL, this function is equivalent to EnumWindows.
        /// Windows 95/98/Me: parentHandle cannot be NULL.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="callbackFunction">
        /// Pointer to an application-defined callback function. For more information, see EnumChildProc.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="param">
        /// Specifies an application-defined value to be passed to the callback function.
        /// </param>
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern int EnumChildWindows(IntPtr parentHandle, Delegate callbackFunction, IntPtr param);

        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieves a handle to the top-level window whose class name and window name match the specified strings. This function does not search child windows.
        /// This function does not perform a case-sensitive search. To search child windows, beginning with a specified child window, use the FindWindowEx function.
        /// <returns>
        /// <param name="className">
        /// The class name or a class atom created by a previous call to the RegisterClass or RegisterClassEx function.
        /// The atom must be in the low-order word of lpClassName; the high-order word must be zero.
        /// If lpClassName points to a string, it specifies the window class name.
        /// The class name can be any name registered with RegisterClass or RegisterClassEx, or any of the predefined control-class names.
        /// If lpClassName is NULL, it finds any window whose title matches the lpWindowName parameter.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="windowName">The window name (the window's title). If this parameter is NULL, all window names match.</param>
        /// If the function succeeds, the return value is a handle to the window that has the specified class name and window name.
        /// If the function fails, the return value is NULL. To get extended error information, call GetLastError. 
        /// </returns>
        /// </summary>
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string className, string windowName);

        /// <summary>
        /// The FindWindowEx function retrieves a handle to a window whose class name and window name match the specified strings.
        /// The function searches child windows, beginning with the one following the specified child window.
        /// This function does not perform a case-sensitive search. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="parentHandle">
        /// Handle to the parent window whose child windows are to be searched. 
        /// If hwndParent is NULL, the function uses the desktop window as the parent window.
        /// The function searches among windows that are child windows of the desktop. 
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="childAfter">
        /// Handle to a child window. The search begins with the next child window in the Z order.
        /// The child window must be a direct child window of hwndParent, not just a descendant window.
        /// If hwndChildAfter is NULL, the search begins with the first child window of hwndParent.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="className">
        /// Pointer to a null-terminated string that specifies the class name or a class atom created by a previous call to the RegisterClass or RegisterClassEx function.
        /// The atom must be placed in the low-order word of lpszClass; the high-order word must be zero.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="windowTitle">
        /// Pointer to a null-terminated string that specifies the window name (the window's title).
        /// If this parameter is NULL, all window names match.
        /// </param>
        /// <returns>
        /// If the function succeeds, the return value is a handle to the window that has the specified class and window names.
        /// If the function fails, the return value is NULL. To get extended error information, call GetLastError. 
        /// </returns>
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr parentHandle, IntPtr childAfter, string className, string windowTitle);

        /// <summary>
        /// Liefert das Handle des NewAppointmentWindow's.
        /// </summary>
        private static IntPtr FindNewAppointmentWindowByCaption(string caption)
        {
            IntPtr newAppointmentWindowHandle = FindWindow(NewAppointmentWindowClass, caption);
            if (newAppointmentWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("NewAppointment Window wasn't found.");
            }
            return newAppointmentWindowHandle;
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _inspectors = Application.Inspectors;
            _inspectors.NewInspector += Inspectors_NewInspector;
        }

        private void Inspectors_NewInspector(Inspector inspector)
        {
            AppointmentItem appointmentItem = inspector.CurrentItem as AppointmentItem;
            if (appointmentItem != null)
            {
                IntPtr appointmentWindow = FindNewAppointmentWindowByCaption(inspector.Caption);

                // Get all child windows based on the new appointment window
                // Unfortunately the social connector handle isn't returned
                GetChildWindows(appointmentWindow);

                // Directly get the social connector based on the class name
                // Unfortunately this returns 0
                IntPtr socialConnectorWindow = FindWindowEx(appointmentWindow, IntPtr.Zero, "MerenguePane", null);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Callback method to be used when enumerating windows.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="handle">Handle of the next window</param>
        /// <param name="pointer">Pointer to a GCHandle that holds a reference to the list to fill</param>
        /// <returns>True to continue the enumeration, false to bail</returns>
        private static bool EnumWindow(IntPtr handle, IntPtr pointer)
        {
            GCHandle gch = GCHandle.FromIntPtr(pointer);
            List<IntPtr> list = gch.Target as List<IntPtr>;
            if (list == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidCastException("GCHandle Target could not be cast as List<IntPtr>");
            }
            Debug.WriteLine("Current Window Handle: {0}, Hex: {1}", handle, handle.ToString("X"));
            list.Add(handle);

            // You can modify this to check to see if you want to cancel the operation, then return a null here
            return true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a list of child windows
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="parent">Parent of the windows to return</param>
        /// <returns>List of child windows</returns>
        public static List<IntPtr> GetChildWindows(IntPtr parent)
        {
            List<IntPtr> result = new List<IntPtr>();
            GCHandle listHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(result);
            try
            {
                EnumWindowProc childProc = EnumWindow;
                EnumChildWindows(parent, childProc, GCHandle.ToIntPtr(listHandle));
            }
            finally
            {
                if (listHandle.IsAllocated)
                {
                    listHandle.Free();
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            Startup += ThisAddIn_Startup;
        }
    }
}
```

Btw. the social connector is only displayed if you directly create a meeting request e.g. go to the calendar, right click --> New meeting request

Any thoughts on this?

Regards,
Lukas

Comment: How could EnumChildWindow not find it? I guess there's a problem with your code. Which you did not show.

Comment: Hi David, there's a Download link above where you can get a demo app.

Comment: Please make a short and complete code sample, and post the code here. We don't care for off site links. They go bad. Remember this question will live forever.

Comment: Hi David, have you been able to reproduce the issue I mentioned above? Any idea why I cannot get the social connector handle?